# how to add 'More...' button on a column of Gridview by jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `TemplateField` in Gridview which may be very long. I want to cut or trim it if it has more than 100 characters and instead replace a button "more..." that if user clicks on it, the whole text will be shown by ***jquery or javascript.***

this is my GridView:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GVProjects" runat="server"  CssClass="GVAdmin">
  
<Columns>  
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Info ">
   <ItemTemplate>
   
     <asp:Label ID="labelinfo" runat="server" CssClass="GVAdmin" 
   Text='<%#  Eval("Information") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                             
  </ItemTemplate>                                    
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

And I want to have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon @Anand Systematix's answer you can modify this to use with `jquery`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
 <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Limit(Eval("Description"),40) %>' 
                Tooltip='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind to limit string

```
protected string Limit(object desc, int maxLength)
{
    var description = (string)desc;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) { return description; }
    return description.Length <= maxLength ? 
        description : description.Substring(0, maxLength)+ "<a class='lnkReadMore' href='javascript:void(0);'>...</a>";
}
```

`jquery` for handling `lnkReadMore` click

```
$('.lnkReadMore').click(function(e)
{
    var labelElement = $(this).closest("[id*='lblDescription']")
    var fullText = $(labelElement).attr("title");
    $(labelElement).text(fullText);
});
```

Comment: what is the function in jquery please? whatever i try is wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by below example :-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
 <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Limit(Eval("Description"),40) %>' 
                Tooltip='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="ReadMoreLinkButton" runat="server"
                Text="Read More"
                Visible='<%# SetVisibility(Eval("Description"), 40) %>'
                OnClick="ReadMoreLinkButton_Click">
      </asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And for code-behind

```
protected bool SetVisibility(object desc, int maxLength)
{
    var description = (string)desc;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) { return false; }
    return description.Length > maxLength;
}

protected void ReadMoreLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = button.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label descLabel = row.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label;
    button.Text = (button.Text == "Read More") ? "Hide" : "Read More";
    string temp = descLabel.Text;
    descLabel.Text = descLabel.ToolTip;
    descLabel.ToolTip = temp;
}

protected string Limit(object desc, int maxLength)
{
    var description = (string)desc;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) { return description; }
    return description.Length <= maxLength ? 
        description : description.Substring(0, maxLength)+ "<a>...</a>";
}
```

**Edited :-**

To use only javascript you can add/call a java-script function from  tag and can remove "OnClick="ReadMoreLinkButton_Click"" from itemtemplate.

Comment: instead of `...` return a `anchor` tag, which will make it a link.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I want to do it only by** jquery or javascript**  as I mentioned in the title because for some reasons I couldn't use Ajax and so I don't want to load page again!

Comment: For this you can add/call a java-script function from <a> tag and can remove  "OnClick="ReadMoreLinkButton_Click"" from itemtemplate.

Comment: @zafy it doesn't need to make an ajax call, at the `anchor` tag returned will have an id or class which you can use in `jquery` for replacing the text with which is stored in `title` attribute